# firebase doesn't showing realtime data inserting and not able to remove data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Anybody have ever faced an issue in firebase where real-time inserting and deletion is not working as previously in firebase console.

How can we revert back?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification

Comment: There is no code with this issue. i'm talking about firebase console where we can able see realtime insert and delete actions

Comment: This may probably be an issue with your browser.

Comment: Currently showing in chrome 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit)

Comment: same issue in firefox too